# Which are the dimensions of a Card Item?

Tags: android, material-design

Following material design, I found [Cards](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage).
But unfortunately i can't found any information about dimensions of cards items of the picture below.

[image]

Please tell me what the dimensions of cards i need to use.
I want to know :

- what the full height and full width of card item?
- what the height of description area in card item(IMG_4130.jpg,IMG_4131.jpg,etc.)

That's all what i need.

Comment: why do you need dimension at all use match_parent for height and width

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs in the exact page you linked, these are not *Cards* - usually represented with a `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` - but *Tiles*.

You will have to implement your own layout for tiles and have the dimensions you wish, because this pattern is not standardized in the docs.

Main differences between cards and tiles:

> 1. Cards have rounded corners.
> 2. Cards can have multiple actions.
> 3. Cards can be dismissible and rearranged.

While:

> 1. Tiles have square corners.
> 2. Tiles have no more than two actions.

So use tiles for homogeneous content with not-so-many actions in it. Dimensions depend on your images, basically.

Answer (score 0):

They can be of any dimension that you want, and are meant to be of different sizes in different use cases, so as to fit the content best

You can check out [Google's material design docs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) for more info :)

EDIT: didn't see that you'd already linked to the docs

Comment: I want to know dimensions only in this case. And i can't found any refers with dimens for this case.

Comment: The width would appear to be 50%, minus some margin (set `layout_width` on each card to `0dp`, and set `layout_weight` to `1`). 

The the height looks to be the same as the width, and you could calculate this in the `onMeasure` method of each of the tiles